# Filtering Python Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to filter my CIFAR-100 ndarray by class index, here is my code:

```
def get_cifar100(folder, class_idx):
    train_fname = os.path.join(folder, 'train')
    test_fname = os.path.join(folder, 'test')
    data_dict = unpickle(train_fname)
    train_data = data_dict['data']
    train_fine_labels = data_dict['fine_labels']
    train_coarse_labels = data_dict['coarse_labels']

    # Filtering process
    filt_tdata = numpy.empty((0))
    for i, v in enumerate(train_coarse_labels):
        if v == class_idx:
            filt_tdata = numpy.append(filt_tdata, train_data[i])

    data_dict = unpickle(test_fname)
    test_data = data_dict['data']
    test_fine_labels = data_dict['fine_labels']
    test_coarse_labels = data_dict['coarse_labels']

    bm = unpickle(os.path.join(folder, 'meta'))
    clabel_names = bm['coarse_label_names']
    flabel_names = bm['fine_label_names']

    return data_dict, filt_tdata, numpy.array(train_coarse_labels), numpy.array(train_fine_labels), test_data, numpy.array(test_coarse_labels), numpy.array(test_fine_labels), clabel_names, flabel_names

datapath = "./data/cifar-100-python"
data_dict, tr_data100, tr_clabels100, tr_flabels100, te_data100,   te_clabels100, te_flabels100, clabel_names100, flabel_names100 =    get_cifar100(datapath, 4)

print(len(tr_data100))
```

I want to filter train_data based on class_idx = 4 (train_coarse_labels). The size of original array is 50000 and it should be 5000 on filtered. But, I got more than its original size (7 million ++). What's wrong with my function? Thanks.